# Inserting Date stamp into cell under a headername

Tags: bash, terminal

I need to insert date/time into a csv file called neworder.csv every time we execute the bash script. The date/time need to be formatted as YYYYDDMM-HRMMSEC

```
HR=hours
MM=minutes
Sec=seconds(Dont really care for this)
```

The header name in the file is called DATEOFORDER. Also this file usually has 3 rows but can have multiple.

Thanks

Comment: Use "date" to generate a date in the format you wish (assign the output to a variable), then use "sed" to insert this value into the first line of any file you wish.  There are plenty of examples on SO how to do each individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date +%Y%d%m"-"%H%M%S
```

The "date" command will give you the date to input to the file.
You can check the format for the date command with `date --help`

Now we need to append this date to the file where you want it.
This can be done with echo: `` echo "`date +%Y%d%m"-"%H%M%S`" >> filename `` Note the two grave characters.
The normal echo command will only append the date to the end of the file. If you have other lines below where you want to paste the date, you can use the "sed" command:

```
# first assign the date to a variable
date=$(date +%Y%d%m"-"%H%M%S)

# now add to the file with sed
sed -i "/LINE ABOVE WHERE THE DATE SHOULD BE/a ${date}" filename
```

Remember to use double quotes so "sed" will interpret variables.
The /a means "add below this line" and the -i  edits the file in place so you won't have temporary copies of the date.

If you executed the code above on this (this being 'filename'):

```
RANDOM TEXT
THIS IS THE LINE ABOVE WHERE THE DATE SHOULD BE, THE DATE SHOULD BE BELOW
RANDOM TEXT
HELLO, WORLD
```

The result would look something like this:

```
RANDOM TEXT
THIS IS THE LINE ABOVE WHERE THE DATE SHOULD BE, THE DATE SHOULD BE BELOW
20171706-003334
RANDOM TEXT
HELLO, WORLD
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date +%Y%d%m"-"%H%M%S.
```

This command will get you the data you need you can then it's just a case of using something like:

```
echo "A,B,$(date +%Y%d%m"-"%H%M%S),C,D" >> somefile
```